# Horizontal only touchpad in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

Im trying to modify the libgdx Touchpad class to only be horizontal movement and not a full circle.  So something like this:

[image]
 But the touch is messed up and doesnt stop the movement within the bounds of the touchpad like it does for the round version.  Heres my version, any help on where Im going wrong would be appreciated:

```
public class HorizontalTouchpad extends Widget {
    private HorizontalTouchpadStyle style;
    boolean touched;
    boolean resetOnTouchUp = true;
    private float deadzoneWidth;
    private final Rectangle knobBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0,0);
    private final Rectangle touchBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0,0);
    private final Rectangle deadzoneBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0,0);
    private final Vector2 knobPosition = new Vector2();
    private final Vector2 knobPercent = new Vector2();

    /** @param deadzoneWidth The distance in pixels from the center of the touchpad required for the knob to be moved. */
    public HorizontalTouchpad (float deadzoneWidth, Skin skin) {
        this(deadzoneWidth, skin.get(HorizontalTouchpadStyle.class));
    }

    /** @param deadzoneWidth The distance in pixels from the center of the touchpad required for the knob to be moved. */
    public HorizontalTouchpad (float deadzoneWidth, Skin skin, String styleName) {
        this(deadzoneWidth, skin.get(styleName, HorizontalTouchpadStyle.class));
    }

    /** @param deadzoneWidth The distance in pixels from the center of the touchpad required for the knob to be moved. */
    public HorizontalTouchpad (float deadzoneWidth, HorizontalTouchpadStyle style) {
        if (deadzoneWidth < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("deadzoneWidth must be > 0");
        this.deadzoneWidth = deadzoneWidth;

        knobPosition.set(getWidth() / 2f, getHeight() / 2f);

        setStyle(style);
        setSize(getPrefWidth(), getPrefHeight());

        addListener(new InputListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                if (touched) return false;
                touched = true;
                calculatePositionAndValue(x, y, false);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchDragged (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
                calculatePositionAndValue(x, y, false);
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                touched = false;
                calculatePositionAndValue(x, y, resetOnTouchUp);
            }
        });
    }

    void calculatePositionAndValue (float x, float y, boolean isTouchUp) {
        float oldPositionX = knobPosition.x;
        float oldPositionY = knobPosition.y;
        float oldPercentX = knobPercent.x;
        float oldPercentY = knobPercent.y;
        float centerX = knobBounds.x;
        float centerY = knobBounds.y;
        knobPosition.set(centerX, centerY);
        knobPercent.set(0f, 0f);
        if (!isTouchUp) {
            if (!deadzoneBounds.contains(x, y)) {
                knobPercent.set((x - centerX) / (knobBounds.getWidth()/2), 0);
                float length = knobPercent.len();
                if (length > 1) knobPercent.scl(1 / length);
                if (knobBounds.contains(x, y)) {
                    knobPosition.set(x, y);
                } else {
                    knobPosition.set(knobPercent).nor().scl(knobBounds.getWidth()/2,0).add(knobBounds.x, knobBounds.y);
                }
            }
        }
        if (oldPercentX != knobPercent.x || oldPercentY != knobPercent.y) {
            ChangeListener.ChangeEvent changeEvent = Pools.obtain(ChangeListener.ChangeEvent.class);
            if (fire(changeEvent)) {
                knobPercent.set(oldPercentX, oldPercentY);
                knobPosition.set(oldPositionX, oldPositionY);
            }
            Pools.free(changeEvent);
        }
    }

    public void setStyle (HorizontalTouchpadStyle style) {
        if (style == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("style cannot be null");
        this.style = style;
        invalidateHierarchy();
    }

    /** Returns the touchpad's style. Modifying the returned style may not have an effect until {@link #setStyle(HorizontalTouchpadStyle)} is
     * called. */
    public HorizontalTouchpadStyle getStyle () {
        return style;
    }

    @Override
    public Actor hit (float x, float y, boolean touchable) {
        if (touchable && this.getTouchable() != Touchable.enabled) return null;
        return touchBounds.contains(x, y) ? this : null;
    }

    @Override
    public void layout () {
        // Recalc pad and deadzone bounds
        float halfWidth = getWidth() / 2;
        float halfHeight = getHeight() / 2;
        float radius = Math.min(halfWidth, halfHeight);
        touchBounds.set(halfWidth, halfHeight, getWidth(),getHeight());
        if (style.knob != null) radius -= Math.max(style.knob.getMinWidth(), style.knob.getMinHeight()) / 2;
        knobBounds.set(halfWidth, halfHeight, getWidth(),getHeight());
        deadzoneBounds.set(halfWidth, halfHeight, deadzoneWidth, getHeight());
        // Recalc pad values and knob position
        knobPosition.set(halfWidth, halfHeight);
        knobPercent.set(0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw (Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        validate();

        Color c = getColor();
        batch.setColor(c.r, c.g, c.b, c.a * parentAlpha);

        float x = getX();
        float y = getY();
        float w = getWidth();
        float h = getHeight();

        final Drawable bg = style.background;
        if (bg != null) bg.draw(batch, x, y, w, h);

        final Drawable knob = style.knob;
        if (knob != null) {
            x += knobPosition.x - knob.getMinWidth() / 2f;
            y += knobPosition.y - knob.getMinHeight() / 2f;
            knob.draw(batch, x, y, knob.getMinWidth(), knob.getMinHeight());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public float getPrefWidth () {
        return style.background != null ? style.background.getMinWidth() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public float getPrefHeight () {
        return style.background != null ? style.background.getMinHeight() : 0;
    }

    public boolean isTouched () {
        return touched;
    }

    public boolean getResetOnTouchUp () {
        return resetOnTouchUp;
    }

    /** @param reset Whether to reset the knob to the center on touch up. */
    public void setResetOnTouchUp (boolean reset) {
        this.resetOnTouchUp = reset;
    }

    /** @param deadzoneWidth The distance in pixels from the center of the touchpad required for the knob to be moved. */
    public void setDeadzone (float deadzoneWidth) {
        if (deadzoneWidth < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("deadzoneWidth must be > 0");
        this.deadzoneWidth = deadzoneWidth;
        invalidate();
    }

    /** Returns the x-position of the knob relative to the center of the widget. The positive direction is right. */
    public float getKnobX () {
        return knobPosition.x;
    }

    /** Returns the y-position of the knob relative to the center of the widget. The positive direction is up. */
    public float getKnobY () {
        return knobPosition.y;
    }

    /** Returns the x-position of the knob as a percentage from the center of the touchpad to the edge of the circular movement
     * area. The positive direction is right. */
    public float getKnobPercentX () {
        return knobPercent.x;
    }

    /** Returns the y-position of the knob as a percentage from the center of the touchpad to the edge of the circular movement
     * area. The positive direction is up. */
    public float getKnobPercentY () {
        return knobPercent.y;
    }

    /** The style for a {@link HorizontalTouchpad}.
     * @author Josh Street */
    public static class HorizontalTouchpadStyle {
        /** Stretched in both directions. Optional. */
        public Drawable background;

        /** Optional. */
        public Drawable knob;

        public HorizontalTouchpadStyle () {
        }

        public HorizontalTouchpadStyle (Drawable background, Drawable knob) {
            this.background = background;
            this.knob = knob;
        }

        public HorizontalTouchpadStyle (HorizontalTouchpadStyle style) {
            this.background = style.background;
            this.knob = style.knob;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't Slider what you want? https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Slider.html

Answer (score 1):

If you only allow horizontal movement it's only x-position that's interesting right? You can set y-position to always be a constant value. To make it stay within the bounds of the touchpad you need a check to make sure it doesn't move outside. So if you define some constants inside the layout method:

```
@Override
public void layout () {
    // Recalc pad and deadzone bounds
    float halfWidth = getWidth() / 2;
    float halfHeight = getHeight() / 2;
    float radius = Math.min(halfWidth, halfHeight);
    touchBounds.set(halfWidth, halfHeight, getWidth(),getHeight());
    if (style.knob != null) radius -= Math.max(style.knob.getMinWidth(), style.knob.getMinHeight()) / 2;
    knobBounds.set(halfWidth, halfHeight, getWidth(),getHeight());
    deadzoneBounds.set(halfWidth, halfHeight, deadzoneWidth, getHeight());

    yPosition = halfHeight;
    minX = style.knob.getMinWidth() / 2;
    maxX = getWidth() - style.knob.getMinWidth() / 2;

    // Recalc pad values and knob position
    knobPosition.set(halfWidth, halfHeight);
    knobPercent.set(0, 0);
}
```

and then when you set the position:

```
.....
if (knobBounds.contains(x, y)) {
    if (x < minX) {
       x = minX;
    }
    if (x > maxX) {
       x = maxX;
    }
    knobPosition.set(x, yPosition);
} else {
    knobPosition.set(knobPercent).nor().scl(knobBounds.getWidth()/2,0).add(knobBounds.x, knobBounds.y);
}
.....
```

Something like that (might need tweeking). You probably have to do a similair check for knobPercent.

Comment: This got me to look in the right direction, had an issue with calculating the percent and setting the bounds correctly for a rectangle vs the circle.  Posting the updated code as an answer for anyone else who might need it

Answer (score 1):

Had to adjust the bounds and how it calculates the location and percent based on it being a rectangle versus a circle.  Here is the updated layout method and calculate method:

```
@Override
    public void layout () {
        // Recalc pad and deadzone bounds
        float halfWidth = getWidth() / 2;
        float halfHeight = getHeight() / 2;
        touchBounds.set(getX(), getY(), getWidth(),getHeight());

        knobBounds.set(getX(), getY(), getWidth(),getHeight());
        deadzoneBounds.set(halfWidth-deadzoneWidth/2, getY(), deadzoneWidth, getHeight());

        yPosition = halfHeight;

        // Recalc pad values and knob position
        knobPosition.set(halfWidth, halfHeight);
        knobPercent.set(0, 0);
    }
```

Added a yPosition variable to make it easy to set the y position everytime

```
void calculatePositionAndValue (float x, float y, boolean isTouchUp) {
        float oldPositionX = knobPosition.x;
        float oldPositionY = knobPosition.y;
        float oldPercentX = knobPercent.x;
        float oldPercentY = knobPercent.y;
        float centerX = knobBounds.width/2;
        float centerY = knobBounds.height/2;
        knobPosition.set(centerX, centerY);
        knobPercent.set(0f, 0f);
        if (!isTouchUp) {
            if (!deadzoneBounds.contains(x, y)) {
                knobPercent.set((x - centerX) / (knobBounds.getWidth()/2), 0);
                float length = knobPercent.len();
                if (length > 1) knobPercent.scl(1 / length);
                if (knobBounds.contains(x, y)) {
                    knobPosition.set(x, yPosition);
                } else {
                    knobPosition.set(knobPercent).scl(knobBounds.getWidth()/2,0).add(knobBounds.width/2, knobBounds.height/2);
                }
            }
        }

        if (oldPercentX != knobPercent.x || oldPercentY != knobPercent.y) {
            ChangeListener.ChangeEvent changeEvent = Pools.obtain(ChangeListener.ChangeEvent.class);
            if (fire(changeEvent)) {
                knobPercent.set(oldPercentX, oldPercentY);
                knobPosition.set(oldPositionX, oldPositionY);
            }
            Pools.free(changeEvent);
        }
    }
```

The big change here was calculating the percent and changing the position when not within the bounds.  It was using getX() for the circle which is the center, but for rectangle it is the bottom left.  So had to change it to the center.